# Ican not access the site. the Wordpress platform, hosting Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ssh

As the name sounds, I'm in big trouble ....
I have hosting on Google's cloud, and I don't have access to a Cpanel.
Today 10.06.2017, I installed a plugin ... something that minimize css and java.
After the first refresh, I have never had access to the site.
**"Error establishing database connection"**
It may be just a coincidence, I don't know ...
I don't have access to phpMyAdmin, showing me error #2002.
can only access SSH, and Cloud Shell.
the big problem is that I have no idea what to do.
my site was:):[EUropa Headlines](http://www.europaheadlines.com)
I've tried several methods to access MySQL from SSH shell, but as you can see, no results.
If you know any model to reset or make back-ups, even if it is the video, thank you in advance
Say that I do not have knowledge, so a helper type copy/paste would be ideal

Thanks!

Comment: Your site is working fine for me. Maybe it was a temporary problem?

Comment: it's down.. all.... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SSH access, just delete your last plugin folder, then, verify your configuration into the file wp-config.php

Comment: so,
I don't know how to access the section where I have the plugin.
and wp-config.php is in phpMyAdmin, where I don't have access ...
If you know the commands to access, or if you want to restore to a back-up please tell me
Thanks!